# How to generate binary data using Cholesky decomposition in R?

Tags: r, probability

```
m <- matrix(nrow=5, ncol=5)  
m <- ifelse(row(m)==col(m), 1, 0.4)  
ch <- chol(m)    # Choleski decomposition  
u <- matrix(rnorm(2000*5), ncol=5)  
uc <- u %*% ch  
cr <- pnorm(uc)  
cr <- qbinom(cr,1,0.5)  
cor(uc)  
cor(cr)
```

The cor(uc) is 0.4. However, I also expected the cor(cr) to be 0.4, but it is around 0.2.
Why the correlation is shrunken?

Comment: The title isn't really a question. Can you phrase it differently?

Comment: Also, avoid using common function names (like `c`) as variable names.

Comment: Why would you expect the outcome from this procedure to yield a correlation of 0.4? I certainly wouldn't. Why do you insist in your title that it must be done by Cholesky?

Comment: Please do not cross-post, SE explicitly discourages this. Please decide which question you want to keep, & delete the other. If you like answers in each venue, flag your Q for moderator attention, & this can be dealt with. You may want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 3):

By converting an interval scaled set of numbers with a given correlation (mostly concentrated around 0) over to a 1/0 scale you, on average, drove the pairs further apart on the squared distance scale. In thinking about this for its implications to coders it is probably that the unnecessary conversion of interval data to binomial data is going to decrease the power of your investigations into the data relationships. An investigation into count data outcomes conducted with Poisson regression is likely to reveal more than if the outcomes were coded into 1/0 depending on whether the counts were above or below any particular cutpoint. There's probably a proof that could be exhibited but demonstration of probability theorems is not what SO is about. If you want a more mathematical explanation, there is always the stats.stackexchange.com interface.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go ahead and copy most of my [answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650982/strange-result-from-a-choleski-decomposition-in-r/13651671#13651671) here:

You may want to look into the literature on **copulas**. I believe that what you are doing here is basically constructing a *Gaussian copula* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29)): maybe this is already obvious to you, maybe not ... For example, http://www.casact.org/library/02pcas/venter.pdf states

> The linear correlation coefficient based on the covariance of two
>   variates is not preserved by copulas. That is, two pairs of correlated
>   variates with the same copula can have different correlations.
>   However, the Kendall correlation, usually denoted by τ, is a constant
>   of the copula. That is, any correlated variates with the same copula
>   will have the τ of that copula.

As suggested by @Glen_b's comment, you don't necessarily need Cholesky to do this -- there are lots of ways to generate correlated multivariate normal Gaussian data (`MASS::mvrnorm` is probably the most widely used R function: it uses an eigenvector rotation).

Comment: Thank @Ben, I tried the copula package. 
`library(copula);
tmp <- normalCopula(0.5, dim=3);
x <- rCopula(10000, normalCopula(0.5, dim=3));
y <- cbind(qbinom(x[,1:3], 1, 0.5))`

`cor(x)` is 0.5,
`cor(y)` is 0.33; how does the 0.33 come up?